# Adjusting a variable then appending to a list in python

Tags: python, list, append

I'm making a noughts and crosses AI using negamax and to do this I must run through all the possible moves you could make from any board state. I'm attempting to do this by appending each possible version of the board to a list however it will only append the final state to the list.

Here is my code:

```
def allPossibleMoves(board, turn):
    l = []
    for i in range(0,3):
        for x in range(0,3):
            if board[i][x] == ' ':
                board[i][x] = turn
                print(board)
                l.append(board)
                board[i][x] = ' '
    return l
```

Comment: Could you provide an input and its expected output?

Comment: You only have a single mutable board in your code -- make copies of it before appending. Also -- your question would be better if it included a [mcve]. In this case, the issue seems clear enough, but whenever code in a question depends upon code defined elsewhere, it is hard to know for certain what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because no matter how many times you append `board` to the list, the `board` variable will point at the same object.

Use the [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) method from the built-in [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module in the `for` loop to make copies of the object:

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to append the same variable over over.

If you know for sure that `board` is a bidimensional array, you can append a list comprehension, like this:

```
l.append([array[:] for array in board])
```

If you don't know the shape of board, I suggest you use the same method as per Ann Zen's answer.

Comment: Nice. But the inner arrays of `board` will still be the same instances of each others.

Comment: Oof, you are right, they'll all be the same copy of the latest updated board. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Good idea. You can implement your first suggestion into this answer: `[array[:] for array in board]`.